# Using git while running virtualenv

Tags: git, virtualenv

I just started using virtualenv for a python project. Is there any issues with initializing git and setting up version control while in the virtualenv? Or, should I deactivate before setting up version control for the project directory? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand the use of pip freeze > requirements.txt in order to create list of packages installed using pip for each virtualenv. Does this suggest I should deactivate before using git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you intend to place your virtualenv into source control (which I would *not* recommend you do), there should be no interference whatsoever when using Git with an active virtualenv.

If you do have your virtualenv folder set up within the project folder, add an entry in `.gitignore` to exclude it, and be sure to include a `requirements.txt` file so that the project's dependencies can be easily installed by anyone accessing the repository.